# Epsilon Delta Partial Continuity Proofs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

### Question

Let's say we have a function:
$$f(x)=
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
3x,\ if\ x\leq2 \\ 
floor(x)+4,\ if\ x>2
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

How do we prove continuity over $(-\infty,2]$ and discontinuity over $Z \cap (2, \infty)$?

### This is where we are so far:

To prove that f(x) is continuous over p = $(-\infty,2]$, we must prove that $\forall$ $\epsilon$ $\in$ $(0,1)$, $\exists$ $\delta > 0$ s.t. $\forall$ q $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$, $|p - q|$ < $\delta$ $\implies$ $|f(p) - f(q)|$ < $\epsilon$.

For continuity over $(-\infty,2]$, there are two cases to handle:

> #### Case 1: $q \leq 2$
>
> $|f(p) - f(q)|$ < $\epsilon$
>
> = $|3p - 3q|$ < $\epsilon$
>
> = $|p - q|$ < $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$
>
> Choose $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{3}$.  Case proven.
>
> #### Case 2: $q > 2$
>
> $|f(p) - f(q)|$ < $\epsilon$
>
> = $|3p - (floor(q) + 4)|$ < $\epsilon$
>
> = $|3p - floor(q) - 4|$ < $\epsilon$
>
> *Where do I go from here?*

For continuity over $(2, \infty]$, there are likewise two cases to handle:

> #### Case 1: $q \leq 2$
>
> $|f(p) - f(q)|$ < $\epsilon$
>
> = $|floor(p) + 4 - 3q|$ < $\epsilon$
>
> *Where do I go from here?*
>
> #### Case 2: $q > 2$
>
> = $|floor(p) + 4 - (floor(p) + 4)|$ < $\epsilon$
>
> *Where do I go from here?*

Thank you!

Comment: There are only discrete points of discontinuity, one at each integer, for the "floor" function over $(2, \infty)$. The function is not discontinuous everywhere, only at these discrete points. It is continuous in between each pair of integers.

Also, I am rather well known for liking to discuss things at length and working through every tiny detail. And even I think that you are overcomplicating things on your $\epsilon -\delta$ proof. Look at some models in good texts and cut way way back.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll fix the problem to reflect that it is only discontinuous over Z greater than 2.  As for detail - our professor wants us to go into this level of detail.  How would you go about proving that the function is discontinuous at each integer?

Comment: I have to get off the computer now. Not ignoring you but real life. Somebody on here should be able to give you some more tips.

Comment: No, it is *only* discontinuous at *integers* greater than 2. Be exact. Say what you mean and mean what you say. (Bonus points for source of that quote).